# Difference between Expression MIB and Enterprise MIB

Tags: snmp, mib

Can anyone please help me out in differentiating between Expression MIB and Enterprise MIB?

I did a lot of searching, but I hardly found anything on Enterprise MIB.

Comment: I never heard of an Expression MIB. Can you give a reference for that term?

Comment: @Jolta, he probably means RFC2982 or DISMAN-EXPRESSION-MIB.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather strange that you use "Expression MIB" and "Enterprise MIB" terms without providing further clarification.

The Expression MIB document should be more carefully described as DISMAN-EXPRESSION-MIB or RFC2982,

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2982.txt?number=2982

However, there is no "Enterprise MIB". Any MIB document that's not part of IETF standards can be called an enterprise MIB document.

Comment: I suspect "enterprise MIB" means any MIBs under `iso(1).org(3).dod(6).internet(1).private(4).enterprises(1)`.

Comment: That's a better way, but still with some grey area. For example, A MIB module can define any entities, some under enterprises and others not. So, should we call that document an "enterprise MIB" or not?